# SharePoint to outlook

Tags: office-integration, outlook

We want users to signup from the intranet (SharePoint 2010) for events/classes. When they do, we want a outlook calender appointment created for the signed up class/meeting.

Presently they add their name in the Excel sheet in the intranet and will have to manually add the appointment into their calendar and some people forget to do it and hence don't get reminders and miss the meeting.

Solutions?

Answer (score 1):

First things first: I have not tried this.  I can't verify it works.

This solution looks like it sends an email with a workflow.  Within the email is a link for the event information in .ics format.  When the user clicks on the link it should prompt Outlook to create an event within the user's calendar.

http://ameyakawale.wordpress.com/2010/05/18/email-a-calendarappointment-link-using-sharepoint-workflow/